# Equivalent codes, one work while the other don't

Tags: list, haskell

I have two codes in Haskell which are the same, both must split a list at a given position ( parameter n), but while one is working the other isn't, why is that happening?

```
divide [] _ = ([],[])
divide (h:t) n 
       | n>0 = ( h:list1 , list2 )
       | otherwise = ([],h:t)
       where (list1, list2) = divide t (n-1)
```

The above code works just fine, but the one below don't.

```
divide [] _ = ([],[])
divide (h:t) n 
       | n>0 = ( h:( divide t (n-1) ) , divide t (n-1) )
       | otherwise = ([],h:t)
```

ghci gives the following message:

> divide.hs:3:29:
>
> ```
>    Couldn't match expected type '[a0]' with actual type '([a0], [a1])'
>    In the return type of a call of 'divide'
>    In the second argument of '<:>', namely ' divide t (n-1) '
>    In the expression: h: divide t (n-1)
> ```

edit:

Just a note, I'm assuming that

```
where (list1, list2) = divide t (n-1)
```

is equivalent to

```
where list1 = divide t (n-1)
      list2 = divide t (n-1)
```

Is my assumption right? Wrong assumptions can lead to even worse conclusions.

Comment: I think the error is self explanatory. `divide t (n-1)` gives a tuple and not a list so you can not append `h` to it in `h:(divide t (n-1)`. Similar is the case for the other part of the tuple as it has to be list and not a tuple again.

Comment: Hmmm, saw your comment after my edit, now i understand clearly what's happening on my code.

Comment: Learn to love "couldn't match expected type Blah with actual type BlahBlah" messages from the compiler. They are extremely informative once you understand how to read them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong.

```
where (list1, list2) = divide t (n-1)
```

is equivalent to

```
where pair = divide t (n-1) 
      list1 = fst pair
      list2 = snd pair
```

The left hand side `(list1, list2)` is a pattern which is lazily matched against the right hand side. It does not assign the same value to multiple variables.